# F# Custom operators that return default value

Tags: f#, operator-overloading

I've defined a custom operator in F# like this:

```
static member (&?) value defaultValue =
    if value = null then
        defaultValue
    else
        value
```

The operator is defined within a type and should be called
in the following scenario:
I'm retrieving information about the system processors using WMI.
Now i want to get the VoltageCaps property, but since that might be null, i want to assign a default value in that case.

```
let voltage = (m.["VoltageCaps"] &? (0 :> obj))
```

Visual Studio tells me "The type 'obj' does not support the operator '&?'"

Am i missing something here or is the operator itself faulty?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your operator takes an arg of type `obj` so you should define it as a standalone function, not a type member.

```
let (&?) (value:obj) (defaultValue:'a) =
    match value with
    | null -> defaultValue
    | _ -> unbox value
```

Now you can do this:

```
let voltage = m.["VoltageCaps"] &? 0
```

I changed it to pattern match `null` due to much better performance than generic equality.